# How can i pass values from two html pages to php?

Tags: php, html

I have 2 html pages :

page1.html

```
<html>
 <body>
 <form action="page2.html" method="post">
 Enter First name: <input type="text" id="text1">
 <input type="submit" value="Next">
 </form>
 </body>
 </html>
```

page2.html

```
 <html>
 <body>
 <form action="test.php" method="post">
 Enter Last name: <input type="text" id="text2">
 <input type="submit" value="Submit">
 </form>
 </body>
</html>
```

Now, i would like to retrieve the value of text1 from page1.html and text2 from page2.html. How can i go about it?

Comment: use forms with method get.

Comment: GET and hidden fields might do the trick, even if i dont understand why you use 2 pages just for first and last name ...

Comment: session in html pages. @Rikesh

Comment: @Jai - I mean if OP's able to change format to `.php`, that could be better option.

Comment: the OP will have to change to `.php` either way to use `POST` or `GET` functions, also missing closing quotes at `method="post>`

Comment: its a sample code which i have shared. But am using nearly 50 fields to pass from one page to another and to php more than that. so i just need some solution in regarding.

Comment: in jsp we can do session variables and retrieve those and can perform but i need it with simple html with some scripts and pass it to php for server side validations

Comment: @pallavipradeep you should use php pages then, there you can get the values with `$_POST['yourfieldattr'];` and if you want it to be done with html pages only then you have to use method `GET` and you can get those from url.

Comment: @Pallavipradeep Taking back my previous comment, it is possible to use php functions in a html page, check out this _[tutorial](https://www.rssinclude.com/blog/36_how_to_run_php_scripts_in_html_or_htm_files)_

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are looking for forms. See this tutorial http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_forms.asp. Post your form data from page1.php to page2.php. On page2.html you can access them via $_POST.

Please be aware: This is not a secure example, just for showing purposes! When you want to show user generated data in your frontend, please use sanitizing and validation http://www.php.net/manual/en/filter.examples.sanitization.php.

page1.php:

```
<form action="page2.php" method="post">
    Enter first name: <input type="text" name="firstName"><br>
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

page2.php

```
<h1>Hey <?php echo $_POST['firstName']; ?></h1>
    <form action="lastpage.php" method="post">
    Enter last name: <input type="text" name="lastName"><br>
    <input type="hidden" name="firstName" value="<?php echo $_POST['firstName']; ?>">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

lastpage.php

```
<h1>Yo, my mate <?php echo $_POST['firstName']; ?> <?php echo $_POST['lastName']; ?>!</h1>
```

Comment: Chris its very good solution but i want from html pages to php and i dont want to burden much my server for simple passing

Comment: php is a server side language.For php to be able to access data from html you will have to pass data to the server.

Comment: @Pallavipradeep Sorry, I don't really understand. What you request is only possible with any form of programming.

Comment: chris i need that page1,page2.php which you have specified as html pages and lastpage as php file

Comment: What is the reason? Most of the times, Apache will look for <?php ?> in html files also and parse them accordingly (if it is configured to do so).